# AIX conditional multiple command execution

Tags: shell, scripting, ksh, aix

hope some one can help. 
I'm trying to execute the following on ksh. 
having a variable named var and a variable named var1.

```
var=
var1=Y
[[ $var1 = "N" ]] || (command 1; var=N)
```

when the above is executed the variable "var" is not assigned the value. The command is being executed but it is like if "var" was out of scope and it was creating a new variable (I tried an echo after the assignment getting the correct value N echoed).

```
[[ $var1 = "N" ]] || (command 1; var=N; echo $var)
```

does someone know a way to work around this?

The reason I'm using the double pipe is to avoid IF statements since I have a very large number of the same conditions.

Thanks

Comment: variables set inside of `( .... )` are local to the subshell `(...)`. What you are seeing is expected behavior. if you must use the subshell, then the simplest thing is the `echo "$var" > /tmp/varFile` and then read `/tmp/varfile` to get the value (there are other solutions, but got with what is easy to debug ;-) ). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks person. I'll take that as the answer but can't mark it. :P. Thanks

Comment: I can write up a more detailed answer, if you need help with how to read `/tmp/varfile` into a variable. Glad this helped. Good luck.

Comment: Commands 'if-then-else-fi' are also usable for such purposes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use command grouping with { ... } instead of ( ... ), as in

```
[[ $var1 = "N" ]] || { command 1; var=N; echo $var; }
```

this avoids subshelling the grouped commands list, and thereby keeps the value assigned to the variable. This works with both AT&T and MirBSD Korn Shells.

Comment: I hope sergiopuy comes back and ticks this... its a much better answer.  It works in bash as well.

Comment: Thanks guys, that worked and though I have already changed the scrip. It will come handy :). Thanks